# CurrentAppSimulator not available for testing In-App Purchase

Tags: visual-studio-2012, in-app-purchase, windows-phone-8, simulator

I have set up Visual Studio 2012 windows phone development environment and everything worked well except the In-App Purchase. The issue I am having is that when I use Windows.ApplicationModel.Store.CurrentApp I don't get any error but for testing, if I use Windows.ApplicationModel.Store.CurrentAppSimulator, I get below error:

```
The type or namespace name 'CurrentAppSimulator' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

It seems that CurrentAppSimulator class is not available in Windows.ApplicationModel.Store package. 
Anybody knows what is wrong ?

I will appreciate any help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows Phone 8 does not have CurrentAppSimulator like Windows Store apps do (note the supported platforms at the bottom of http://bit.ly/15HdfbR).

Instead, you'll need to use the techniques outlined here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj681689%28v=vs.105%29.aspx

These steps describe how to download and use the Mock In-App Purchase Library to simulate in-app purchases on Windows Phone 8.

The Mock In-App Purchase Library is available here: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/Mock-In-App-Purchase-33080f0c

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks Gary for explanation.